# How to add multiple geofences for WP app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1, geofencing

I'm trying to develop a location based reminder app using geofences. When I'm using just ane locaiton, it's working perfectly. But when I add two locations, it works only with the first added location. No error or exception appear. But second location doesn't appear at all. I couldn't find a reason for this.

```
    BasicGeoposition pos1 = new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 6.931522, Longitude = 79.842005 };
    BasicGeoposition pos2 = new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = 6.978166, Longitude = 79.927376 };

        Geofence fence1 = new Geofence("loc", new Geocircle(pos1, 100));
        Geofence fence2 = new Geofence("loc", new Geocircle(pos2, 100));

        try
        {
            monitor.Geofences.Add(fence1);
            monitor.Geofences.Add(fence2);
        }
```

This is how I created the locations and added to the geofences. Then called with a loop;

```
var reports = sender.ReadReports();
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
        {
            foreach (GeofenceStateChangeReport changeReport in reports)
            {
                if (changeReport.NewState == GeofenceState.Entered)
                {
                    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async () =>
                        {
                            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("u re in the location");
                            await dialog.ShowAsync();
                        });
                }
                if (changeReport.NewState == GeofenceState.Exited)
                {
                    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async () =>
                        {
                            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("u exited from the location");
                            await dialog.ShowAsync();
                        });

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't adding two fences. In fact you are just trying to overwrite an existing one:

```
Geofence fence1 = new Geofence("loc", new Geocircle(pos1, 100));
Geofence fence2 = new Geofence("loc", new Geocircle(pos2, 100));
```

`loc` is they key you provided for your fence - and this key should be unique (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geofencing.geofence.aspx#constructors). Try:

```
Geofence fence1 = new Geofence("loc1", new Geocircle(pos1, 100));
Geofence fence2 = new Geofence("loc2", new Geocircle(pos2, 100));
```

I'd suggest you to encapsulate adding a new fence into a method since you should also check for existing  fences:

```
private void addGeoFence(Geopoint gp, String name, double radius)
{
    // Always remove the old fence if there is any
    var oldFence = GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Where(gf => gf.Id == name).FirstOrDefault();
    if (oldFence != null)
        GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Remove(oldFence);
    Geocircle gc = new Geocircle(gp.Position, radius);
    // Listen for all events:
    MonitoredGeofenceStates mask = 0;
    mask |= MonitoredGeofenceStates.Entered;
    mask |= MonitoredGeofenceStates.Exited;
    mask |= MonitoredGeofenceStates.Removed;
    // Construct and add the fence with a dwelltime of 5 seconds.
    Geofence newFence = new Geofence(new string(name.ToCharArray()), gc, mask, false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), DateTimeOffset.Now, new TimeSpan(0));
    GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Add(newFence);
}
```

Comment: It's just the full constructor: `Geofence(String,IGeoshape,MonitoredGeofenceStates,Boolean,TimeSpan,DateTime,TimeSpan)` where the last ones are: single use, dwell time, start time, duration of the geofence. For more information refer to the link I posted with the answer. You can see all possible constructors there.

Comment: I tried everything except this. Thank you very much for your help. I thought about your suggetion. But can I ask you about the last  parameter that you're passing when creating a geofence?? What do I need to pass If I want to check it continuously?  Again thank you bery much and I really appreciate your help